# How to "expand" an English sentence

Tags: algorithm, tensorflow, deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding

I would like to get some steps and resources about, how to build program to expand a sentence in English.

For example, if an input sentence is

> `"My father is coaching and refereeing soccer and basketball."`

Then the program would output four sentences:

- `"My father is coaching soccer."`
- `"My father is coaching basketball."`
- `"My father is refereeing soccer."`
- `"My father is refereeing basketball."`

The generated sentences must be valid English sentences and their meaning must follow from the meaning of the input sentence.

Comment: What if the sentence has "or", or "nor", or "either", ... or "plays more soccer than basketball", "likes artists and their works",...etc. The variation of language is enormous.

Comment: I suggested some methods for you

Answer (score 0):

This is not easy at all , if you want to use an AI it will need a huge amount of data and you cant event garantee the exact English sentence meaning , but still i can suggest to you two methods :

- **The AI method** :

You can use a `Recurrent Neural Network` with `LSTM` , the idea is to inject as input your sentence ( which will be transformed using one of the NLP methods ) in your `One to Many` model , to have the different expanded number of sentences as output

*Example :*

```
Input                | Output
'i play xbox and ps' | [ 'i play xbox' , 'i play ps' ]
```

---

- **The Classic method** :

Here you have to use a class with the following attributes `{ subject , verb , object }` and when you want to give an input , you'll have to precise each word of this input as its type , each of the attributes is a list which will append words , and then to expand it you'll parse these lists to see how many objects and verbs you have

*Example ( in Java ) :*

```
// Input : "i play xbox and ps"
Sentence sc = new Sentence();
sc.setSubject("i");
sc.setVerb("play");
sc.addObject("xbox");
sc.addObject("ps");

// for each object you'll do the following
for ( String object : sc.getObject() ) {
    System.out.println( sc.getSubject() + sc.getVerb() + object ) ;
}

// Output : i play xbox
//        : i play ps
```

This is just a simple example but you can think of a way to make the process of adding verbs and objects automatic